# Why aren't these submenus appearing in IE?

Tags: html, css, cross-browser, doctype, submenu

Not sure what the issue is here... Submenus (under services and towns tabs) work fine in every browser but IE.

http://fingelly.idxre.com/idx/officeMap.cfm?cid=47735#-

They work fine in IE from the other pages on the site (example: http://fingelly.com/about-us/)

But not from the listings or agent pages that are just approximating the rest of the site's template via a 3rd party for the real estate data.... The CSS is the same as fas as I can tell but obviously something's throwing it off. I've tried tinkering with z-index on the submenus and also specifying overflow visible on the menu and its parent containers.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have no [document type definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Type_Definition). This tells the browser which rendering mode to use. By default IE uses "everything is broken" mode.

Comment: Nor does he have a <head> or <body> element. :/

Comment: I can confirm the document type definition is the correct answer, when I changed the mode via IE8 dev tools, to IE 8 standards mode the menu worked correctly.

Comment: By default IE uses "everything is broken" mode. made me laugh +1

Comment: thanks... annoying thing is i can't directly add that.. will cry to the 3rd party idx provider that their template is lacking/invalid.

Answer (score 3):

That page is missing several things, such as:

- A doctype.
- `<html>` opening and closing tags.
- `<head>` opening and closing tags.
- `<body>` opening and closing tags

It looks like you've forgotten to add some includes to the top and bottom of the file (or they aren't being loaded, in any case).

As it is at the moment, [it's *hopelessly invalid*](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Ffingelly.idxre.com%2Fidx%2FofficeMap.cfm%3Fcid%3D47735%23-&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0):

> Errors found while checking this
>   document as HTML 4.01 Transitional!
>
> Result: **361 Errors, 134 warning(s)**

You should really fix the page properly by resolving as many of those validator errors as possible, but you can "make it work" by adding these lines to the top:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" dir="ltr" lang="en-US">
```

*(That's your version of the XHTML 1.0 Strict doctype, copied from your working page)*

*(This works and fixes the submenus, I tested it)*